# kendoui chart striplines

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, charts, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo UI.  I have a mvc 4.0 website.  I have a chart.  I'm trying to find a way to put strip lines on a Kendo UI strip chart.  I've looked through the documentation, but I have not found anyway to do this in mvc.  Has anyone done this?  How would I put a strip line on a kendo ui dataviz mvc chart?

I have two images that show what I have and what I want.  How do I upload an image into StackOverflow?

What I have.
[image: What I have]

What I want.
[image: What I want]

Comment: For adding images to SO use image button while editing or the short cut `<ctrl>-G`

Comment: thanks.  once my reputation is over 10, I'll add the images.

Comment: +1 ... a little help :-)

Comment: Ok, I put some images in.

Comment: If I had a way to determine the X and Y coordinates of a div element based upon the content, I could use this method "[link to kendo ui forums](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/dataviz/chart/add-vertical-lines-at-specific-points-in-a-stacked-area-chart.aspx)" from the kendoui website forums.